# Adding more custom entities into pretrained custom NER Spacy3

Tags: vector, nlp, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model, spacy-3

I've a huge amount of textual data and wanted to add around 50 different entities. Initially when I started working with it, I was getting memory error. As we know spacy can handle 1,00,000 tokens per GB and maximum up to 10,00,000. So I chunked my dataset into 5 sets and using annotator created multiple JSON file for the same. Now I started with one JSON and successfully completed creating the model and now I want to add more data into it so that I don't miss out any tags and there's a good variety of data is used while training in the model. Please guide me how to proceed next.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Do you have 50 entity types (like PERSON, LOCATION, etc) or 50 values (like John, Jane, Sally, etc.)? You say you had to divide up your dataset, but are your individual documents very long? The limits you mention are only relevant for single docs. It's also not clear what you had a problem with.

Comment: Hi Polm23,
I've 50 entity type of my business case. If I append all the text as a single paragraph the corpus length increases, that why I thought of splitting the corpus into multiple subset.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned some points of confusion in a comment, but assuming that your issue is how to load a large training set into spaCy, the solution is pretty simple.

First, save your training data as multiple `.spacy` files in one directory. You do not have to make JSON files, that was standard in v2. For details on training data see [the training data section of the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data). In your config you can specify this directory as the training data source and spaCy will use all the files there.

Next, to avoid keeping all the training data in memory, you can specify `max_epochs = -1` (see [the docs on streaming corpora](https://spacy.io/usage/v3-1/#streaming-corpora)). Using this feature means you will have to specify your labels ahead of time as covered in the docs there. You will probably also want to shuffle your training data manually.

That's all you need to train with a lot of data.

The title of your question mentions adding entities to the pretrained model. It's usually better to train from scratch instead to avoid catastrophic forgetting, but you can see a guide to doing it [here](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/ner_demo_update).

Comment: Thank you @Polm23 !

I'll definitely give a try to what you said and will let you know the outcomes.

Comment: I tried what you commented but I'm getting memory error. 
Aborting and saving the final best model. Encountered exception:
RuntimeError('CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 540.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB
total capacity; 11.54 GiB already allocated; 209.75 MiB free; 12.97 GiB reserved
in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting
max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory
Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF')

Comment: Hard to say without a lot more detail, but you might have very long single documents? If your documents are larger than a few paragraphs you might try splitting them up.

Comment: Yes, I do have a very large document, but I have distributed them into chunks and broke it down to as many as 30 spacy files which I'm feeding for training. We can connect at https://www.linkedin.com/in/shubhamg515/

Comment: Can I train a single NER Model multiple time by adding fresh chunks of data ? to avoid memory issue ?

Comment: Even if I split the dataset in fewer sets how will I overcome the Catastrophic interference?